# if else with a link doesn't work

Tags: php, html

If $item not equal to false then echo first link, I then used onclick, but the problem is it seem it always goes to 2nd link. I inspected the $item, it's true, but how come it escaped the if scope? my markup as below:

```
<div>

<?php

if($item !== false){ ?>

<a onclick="window.open('<?php echo $item['2nd']; ?>');"> 

<?php   }else{ ?>

<a href="<?php echo $item['url']; ?>">

<?php }?>

    <div class="content">
    </div>

    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code conflicts what you're saying. "If `$item` not equal to true" would mean you would write `if ($item != true)`

Comment: "If $item not equal to true then first link" is not `if($item !== false)`

Comment: FYI, the way to say "not equal" is `!=`, not `!==`. The latter means not identical.

Comment: @sjagr my bad, edited my question, pls see again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [strict "not equal" comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which you probably didn't mean to do.

From your code, it appears that `$item` is an array, but the line `if ($item !== false)` specifically checks if `$item` is a **boolean false**.  If `$item` is an array, then the if statement will always return false because `$item` isn't a boolean.